# JNA and how to capture a screenshot of minimized window

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

Like in title, does it is possible to take a screenshot of minimized window?
I have already made some research but I didn't found solution.

Comment: Have you found a way to do it in native code?  If the window doesn't actually exist or isn't represented by a backing buffer, chances are the image data doesn't exist either.

Comment: Seems that there is no solution for this.

Comment: this totally depends on the OS and on the Window Manager for which OS are you looking for?

Comment: @PDS ..........